# Unable to execute Hibernate Query in iReport. Says "not mapped"

Tags: java, hibernate, jasper-reports, ireport, netbeans-8

I am trying to create a report for my web application. I am using hibernate with mysql.

[image: here]

Here is the image showing the error when trying to execute a simple hql. 
my query is "from `GEN_BILLSETTINGS`" and i get the result as

> "ERROR:GEN_BILLSETTINGS is not mapped[from GEN_BILLSETTINGS]".

I do have that mapped in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. I did add the hibernate.cfg.xml in classpath for the iReport plugin, the class files folder and also jdbc driver. what might be the possible error here??

Comment: Can you post your `hibernate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: HQL doesn't use table names. It use entity names. I really hope you didn't name any of your classes `GEN_BILLSETTINGS`.